Probabilistic game theory (Continuous game to discrete game analysis)
You are participating in a game with two other people. Each person writes a number from
1 to 100. The person who bids the highest number loses, and pays the other two players the
number they wrote. For example, P1, P2, P3 chose 40,50, and 60 respectively, then P3 must pay 50 to P2 and 40 to P1. What is your strategy? (Note in this question I'm not looking for the strategy of this game in particular, please continue reading)
My attempt: Start with the two-player scenario. In the continuous version of the game where the choice is made in the interval [0,1], let $f(x)dx$ represent the probability of me picking a number in the interval $[x,x+dx]$. Let $y$ be the choice made by player 2. If we view the problem as a Lagrangian optimization of my payoff (or equivalently if we apply the indifference criterion), we find that for any $y$, my payoff should be the same (and is zero since the game is symmetric, but this fact will not contribute much to finding the strategy). Thus we have:
$$\text{Payoff given }~y = const = \int _{0}^y xf(x)dx - y \int_y^1 f(x)dx $$
differentiating twice wrt $y$ and solving for $f$ is straightforward and gives $f\propto x^{-3/2}$.
The actual question. Going back to the discrete version: the probability of me picking number $i$ should be $\int_{(i-1)/100}^{i/100}{f}$. Is this correct? i.e. does this transition from continuous to discrete gives the stationary mixed strategy in the original game?

Why would anybody bid more than the minimum?

I guess the rules are ambiguous.  What does it mean to write that "and pays the other two players the number they wrote"?  Who is "they"?  I read it as saying the high bidder must pay their bid to each of the other two players.  That is, If $A$ were foolish enough to bid $100$, then $A$ would have to pay out $200$ (trusting that nobody else bid so high).  But perhaps my interpretation is incorrect.

@lulu the highest (say 3) pays player i what player i bid

Ok, that's really not clear.  I suggest editing for clarity.  My question still stands, though under this interpretation there is at least some argument for bidding up.  Still, if I bid the minimum, $1$, I can not lose and I might win which seems very attractive.  Note too, that in the scenario in which I break even (everybody bids $1$), bidding higher would have produced a loss.

@lulu Yes I considered that (picking 1 seems like a good pure strategy), but I'm not sure this is the optimal one. Perhaps since it attains the value of the game then it's optimal? In any case my question is concerned with the transition from the continuous version of the game to the discrete one

I'd think the usual sort of argument would work.  Nobody should ever bid $100$ as there are no winning scenarios at all.  Thus, $100$ is not a possible bid.  But then, nobody should bid $99$ since, again, there are no winning scenarios.  And so on.

@lulu I agree, but consider that player 3 is just a random generator of integers from 1 to 100. How to find an optimal strategy now? Picking 1 is definitely not optimal, so I would proceed as I did above by converting to [0,1] and finding a mixed strategy. Do you think this will work? Or is there a better method?

Is that part of the game?  Obviously changing the game rules will change the strategy.  But, sure.  If I know you are planning on bidding randomly, I should bid something.

I am not certain that the avenue of attack of the continuous problem presented above is a good way to approach the discrete problem. Furthermore, it seems that the equation solved above is solved without taking the boundary conditions into account; if $f(x)$ is assumed continuous everywhere, the only admissible solution to the equation is $f(x)=0$, since it can be shown that, after taking a derivative, $f(1)=0$, which trivializes the solutions.
It is easy to see that in the two-player discrete game  the Nash equilibrium is when all players wage on 1. As mentioned in the comments, OP would like to know what the strategy should be when the strategy of the second player is fixed. I will assume that P1 is attempting to optimize his strategy against P2, who has a fixed strategy. Assume $c_1<...<c_n$ is an ordered sequence of bets that can be waged. P2 chooses a fixed strategy that selects said bets with probability $q_1,...,q_n$, while P1 considers optimal strategy $p_1,...,p_n$, to be determined. Payoff function can be defined as
$$P_o(i,j)=\begin{Bmatrix}c_i&i<j\\-c_j&i>j\\0& i=j\end{Bmatrix}$$ This definition takes care of the edge case when two rolls are the same, while keeping the game zero-sum. P1 can attempt to optimize the expected payoff, which reads
$$E(P_0)=\sum_{ij} P_o(i,j)p_iq_j=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\left(c_i\sum_{k=i+1}^n q_k-\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} c_kq_k\right), 0\leq p_i\leq 1,~~~ \sum_{i=1}^np_i=1 ~~$$
Since the payoff is linear in the strategy, this problem can be recast into standard LP problem form, by eliminating $p_n$ for example. Then for $n\geq 3$ the following equivalent form can be used to find the optimal strategy:
$$\max_{p_1,...,p_{n-1}} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_ip_i-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}c_kq_k\\0\leq p_i\leq 1,~~~~~~ i=1,...,n-1\\p_1+...+p_{n-1}\leq 1$$
$$a_i=c_i q_i+\sum_{k=i+1}^{n-1}(c_i+c_k)q_k+c_iq_n$$
This form also highlights the positivity of the coefficients of the linear function. The constraints describe the standard $n-1$ simplex, with its vertices given by the unit vectors $(p_i)_j=\delta_{ij}, ~{j=1,..., n-1}$. It is then clear that the maximum profit can be made by finding which coefficient is the largest, which corresponds to a pure strategy with all $p_i=0$ except the one with the largest coefficient and the profit made is $\max_i(a_i)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{c_kq_k}$. However, if several of these coefficients are equal, then certain probabilistic strategies may become optimal, but the pure ones remain optimal anyway.
Example: Consider the $n=3$ case with $c_k=k,~ 1\leq k\leq 3$. The payoff function is
$$E(P_o)=(1+2q_2)p_1+2(1-q_1)p_2$$
For $q_1+q_2>1/2$ the opponent is making smarter choices with on average smaller waged bets, and the optimal strategy is to always wage $c_1$ with $p_1=1$. On the other hand, for $q_1+q_2<1/2$ P2 is making stupid choices more often and thus it is more profitable to always wage $c_2$. The edge case $q_1+q_2=1/2$ is degenerate; every strategy satisfying $p_1+p_2=1$ is optimal with profit $3/2-q_2$, and this is the only case where mixed strategies are optimal.
Continuous case:
For a wide class of P2 strategies, it can be shown that the optimal strategy requires P1 to wage only on a single bet. Suppose that the strategies for P1,P2 are $p(x), q(x), ~x\in [0,1]$ respectively. The payoff function is
$$E(P_o)=\int_{0}^1 p(x)dx\left(x\int_{x}^1q(y)dy -\int_0^xyq(y)dy:=\int_0^1I(x)p(x)dx\right)$$
Assuming $q(x)$ is continuous, then it is true that $I(x)$ is also continuous and attains its maximum in $[0,1]$. Denote one of the maximizers $x_0: I(x)\leq I(x_0)~~x\in[0,1]$. Then
$$E(P_o)=I(x_0)+\int_0^1 f(x)(I(x)-I(x_0))\leq I(x_0)$$
and the maximum can be attained by the point mass distribution $f(x)=\delta(x-x_0)$.
Example: P2 bets uniformly at random and $I(x)=x-3x^2/2$. Then one can explicitly show
$$E(P_o)=\int_0^1(x-3x^2/2)f(x)dx=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{3}{2}\int_0^1(x-1/3)^2f(x)dx\leq 1/6$$
and the maximum profit is made by waging always at $x=1/3$.

If the all the players strategies are symmetric then there cannot be a mixed strategy Nash Equilibrium. This is because, as you stated the expected payout would be 0. However, a profitable deviation can be found because always plying 1 can never lose you the game and hence the payout is positive. This makes playing 1 strictly dominates any mixed strategy that has a non-unit probability of playing 1. Hence, the only symmetric strategy which is a Nash Equilibrium is everyone playing 1.
If you know that someone else is playing a certain strategy, you can definitely find a best response strategy to this, but that does not seem to be asked in this question.
